# Highcharts - reduce the space between zero data line and x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am trying to reduce the space between zero data line and x-axis but no luck,
I would appreciate help on this fiddle

`softThreshold :true`

http://jsfiddle.net/kunalnavhate/vy3s34vh/

Thanks in advance

[image: Red line shows the space which I want to reduce]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use marginBottom for making your plotArea smaller:

```
chart: {
  marginBottom: 240
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy3s34vh/1/

Another idea is to set xAxis.offset parameter:

```
xAxis: {
  offset: -110
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy3s34vh/2/